# What data structure for an array of bit flags?

Tags: arrays, haskell, bitflags

I'm porting some imperative code to Haskell. My goal is to analyze an executable, therefore each byte of the text section gets assigned a number of flags, which would all fit in a byte (6 bits to be precise).

In a language like C, I would just allocate an array of bytes, zero them and update them as I go. How would I do this efficiently in Haskell?

In other words: I'm looking for a ByteString with bit-wise access and constant time updates as I disassemble more of the text section.

Edit: Of course, any kind of other data structure would do if it was similarly efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a vector with any data type that's an instance of the [`Bits` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html), for example `Word64` for 64 bits per element in the vector. Use an unboxed vector if you want the array to be contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 9):

The implementation for unboxed arrays of `Bool`-s in [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0) is a packed bitarray. You can do mutable updates on such arrays in the [ST Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html) (this is essentially the same runtime behaviour as in C).

Comment: These are both excellent answers, but I think I go with gspr's because it seems more idiomatic to me.

Comment: @Sebastian: `vector` doesn't pack Bool-s into bits, therefore you have to write your own wrapper if you want to read/write specific bits. Most of the time `vector` is a better choice because of the richer API, but here `array` is probably simpler.

Comment: I think I will allocate one byte for each element anyway, because I *think* that would be more performant from an element access perspective. Also it feels like implementing my flags on top of `Bits` is somehow more convenient than 6 consecutive `Bool`s, however that may be subjective.

Comment: @Sebastian valid points, I retract my opinion about array being preferable here.

Comment: Although the votes beg to differ. Maybe I'm missing something? I will be able to tell in a few days.